# Facebook SSO error passing reference of App Delegate

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I followed the example SSO on Facebook's developer website but am getting a strange warning message when I call the authorize message:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];

    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"(my app's ID number)"];
    [facebook authorize:nil delegate:self];

    //[_window addSubview:viewController.view];
    //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO animated:YES];

    return YES;
}
```

The second line shows up with the warning: "Sending QueryTestingAppDelegate to parameter of incompatible type 'id'.

The project builds and runs, but won't do anything Facebook-related.

(I do have the correct App ID # filled in in the code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the AppDelegate header file, did you ensure it implemented the FBSessionDelegate protocol?

i.e.

```
#import "FBConnect.h"

@interface QueryTestingAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, FBSessionDelegate>
```

The Facebook documentation isn't terribly clear on this point but I think that should fix the warning.

Comment: Oh Lord you made that look easy, great fix! Could you explain what went on there for future reference?

Comment: @Chris The Facebook object needs a delegate to act on it's behalf for when your app receives responses from Facebook. For the SSO stuff, this is typically done either in the AppDelegate or a wrapper object. Because you hadn't told the compiler that your AppDelegate will understand what to do when the Facebook object sends it a message, it assumed it wouldn't understand it. I think the Facebook documentation omits that line for the SSO stuff but it should become more clear when you start making Graph API requests :)